# local docker Repos keep getting bigger and bigger

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

i make my first steps with docker repos in artifactory (5.1.3) and theres something that scares me a little bit.

I pushed different tags from the same docker image (abaout 500MB) to a repo.
I'd expected that storage use and size of the repo would stay at about 500 MB.

But with 5 Image-Versions in it, for example, the repo is about 2,5 GB in size.

Also the the "Max Unique Tags" setting in the local docker repo settings has no effect - i set 3 but nothing is deleted - there are again 5 versions.

With this behaviour we will fill our storage system by the end of the month easily - did i miss something or is this docker stuff in artifactory still beta ?

Comment: Can you provide the `Dockerfile` of those images? Also, what did you change between those pushes? Just the tag?

Comment: yes at last i changed tag only so binarys stayed identical - but it consumed the full amount of disk space of the image in artifactory.

Comment: are all the tags in the same Artifactory repository? how did you measure the repository size? have you looks at the storage summary page?

Comment: yes all in the same repo - i checked size in artifactory gui with "Artifact Count / Size: Show" and on console with 'ncdu'. The Max Unique Tags Feature seems to work on a cron base or something like that becaus today 2 of the with Image Versions were gone and in trash can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifactory is physically storing the layers for those tags only once, so the actual storage being used should be ~500MB (deduplication). 
The reported size you are seeing in the UI (artifacts count / size) is the amount of physical storage that would be occupied if each artifact was a physical binary (not just a link). Since deduplication can occur between different repositories, there is no good way of reporting the physical storage size per repository (one image/tag/layer can be shared between multiple repositories).
In the [Storage Summary](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Monitoring+Storage) page you can see both the physical storage size used by Artifactory and how much you gained by deduplication.